# Why any modern CPU masks 5 lower bits in a CL register for shifting operations

Tags: assembly, shift-register, register

I'm digging into left and right shift operations in ASM.

From IA-32 Intel Architecture Software Developer’s Manual 3

> All IA-32 processors (starting with the Intel 286 processor) do mask
>   the shift count to 5 bits, resulting in a maximum count of 31. This
>   masking is done in all operating modes (including the virtual-8086
>   mode) to reduce the maximum execution time of the instructions.

I'm trying to understand the reasoning behind this logic. Maybe it works as it works because on a hardware level it is hard to implement shift for all 32 (or 64) bits in a register using 1 cycle?

Any detailed explanation would help a lot!

Comment: Why would you want to shift all 32 bits?

Comment: @Andyaka the question is not "why I want to do so". The question is "why does it work this way?". It is just seems weird, since the SSE shift instructions (PSLL* etc.) do not mask the shift count.

Comment: Why would anyone want to shift all 32 bits then?

Comment: @Andyaka because it leads us to an inconsistency in shifting behavior. Please, if you know the answer tell me. If not then stop trolling.

Comment: Part of the reason is, C has banned shifting beyond word length so there is no need for other behaviors. Also shifting beyond word length would probably return 0 and can easily be handled as a conditional.

Comment: One motivation for this design is to save bits in the instructions. Most of the time the shift amount is an immediate and is encoded directly in the instructions. So once the code is compiled its already masked. The register version could implement a variety of behaviors, e.g. saturate at int max or min on some dsps.

Comment: @user3528438 The motivation was not to save bits as it is specified as an immediate byte anyway. On a 8086/8088, you can either shift implicitly by one, or shift by amount in CL register, limit being 255. From 80186/80188 onwards, including the 80286, it was possible to shift also by immediate byte value, but all shifts were limited to a 5-bit value, because each shift step took 1 clock cycle. The registers were also 16-bit so there was no need to shift any more than 5-bit amount. If I say "shl ax,255", it assembles fine and opcode immediate byte is 255.

Comment: @Justme What about RISC machines?

Comment: @user3528438 This question is not about RISC machines, they can do whatever they like. This question is about x86 architecture CPUs running x86 code in 16-bit or 32-bit mode. The limit is obviously different for running 64-bit x86 code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As said in the 286 programming reference, they mask the count to limit shift and rotate instruction execution time. These did not have a barrel shifter. Basically the CPU would sit in a loop that shifts data and decrements CL until CL is zero. Earlier CPUs such as 8086 could accept 255 in CL so it would take just needlessly long to execute. And limiting to 5 bits is enough, as that allows shifting of 16-bit registers via carry.

Comment: Thank you! In your last sentence `that allows shifting of 16-bit registers via carry` you specify 16-bit registers. So in an old good times we could do `x << 16 = 0`, right? If so, why did they implement `x<<32 = x`?

Comment: Because you have 16 bit registers, you must be able to shift 16 bit positions at minimum to be compatible, for example shifting any bit to carry bit. So you need 5 bits to indicate how many positions you want to shift, and this limits the positions to shift between 0 and 31 positions.

Comment: Thank you for clarification. I'm sorry, but I'm not a native english speaker and it is very hard for me to translate your first sentence `Because you have 16 bit registers, you must be able to shift 16 bit positions at minimum to be compatible, for example shifting any bit to carry bit.` Could you please rewrite it in a more simpler or detailed manner?

Comment: When the limit to mask shifting was made in 80186/80188 and 80286, it did break compatibility with old code 8086/8088 code, but in real world code, maximum shift or rotate value ever needed was 16, or 17 tops, and for that, 5 bits is needed which allows shifting or rotating up to count of 31. No real world code would ever need to rotate or shift more than that 17 bits, and if some 8086/8088 code really used shifts or rotates with more than 31 counts, the code needed to be rewritten to run on any later CPU.

Comment: thank you for your amazing explanation!